# Networking or Internet Problems

Tags: wireless-networking, wired-networking

I have recently had my ISP  install a router for my office in the comms room of the building and now need to get my nighthawk d7000  in my actual office to connect through the floor back to the ISP router in the Comms room to enable me to have WiFi for all of my laptop's for all 12 of us to work off wirelessly.

I am not very technical but from what I can see, it is a micro filter Outreach MK4 from BT  and I have tried to get them to help but it hasn't been a very good experience with them on the phone and they are trying to charge me to come out again. In the comms room is my router from the ISP and also all of the patches in the cabinet which I have now added a switch to connect to the patches supplies by the landlord which comnect through the floor into my office so I am now getting internet through ethernet into my office  from the router in the Comms Room which is 100m from my office.  The Comms room is for the whole building with public hallways leading to it so I can't use repeaters or extenders in those public spaces as it isn't part of my lease agreement.  I have just had the internet installed today and all my staff are due in on Monday expecting to get back to work so I really need to figure this out quickly. Is anyone able to help me with a simple fix for this?

Comment: Presumably you have an Ethernet connection in your office from the ISP Router.   Connect the WAN port on your router to the Ethernet outlet (I assume you want this to a be separate subnet). Set up the WAN for a DHCP connection (Static is better if you know what IP address to use) and then you should be able to connect by Ethernet to your Office router. Set up the Wi-Fi.  I do as above for some clients.

Comment: You have a working Ethernet connection in your own office with working internet, correct?   So then look at the back of your own router. WAN connection at the back. Connect this WAN jack by an Ethernet cable to the working network connection above. Start up the router and you should have Internet from one of the Ethernet LAN outlets

Comment: That's right. Ethernet is working fine from the ISP router. For some reason when I plug the ethernet into my router from the ISP, it doesn't pick up the internet. The light doesn't even glow red. If i take it back into the comms room and connect it to the patch or router then it at least glows red but doesn't get internet either.   I will give it a try the way that you have explained it first thing tomorrow.  Thank you fro replying and sorry if I sound like I don't know what I am doing. ( I don't know what I am doing.

Comment: Make sure you connect the WAN port of your router to the network (office or comm room - does not matter). Try to have a spare router to test with

Comment: Wan port. Is that rj11?

Comment: It should be labeled WAN and it is RJ45 (NOT RJ11 which is a phone line).  If your own router is ONLY for DSL, it is not going to work. Make sure about that, and get a different router if need be.

Comment: The router in the Comms room is connected to the ISP box from the wall with a rj11 or DSP cable.

Comment: That is fine. That just means your comm room connection is DSL. No issue. But your router must be plain Ethernet and not be a modem. You should get a simple router on your way to the office.

Comment: This makes sense. In my old office i never had this issue. When we moved office I brought the same hardware that I had before to the new office but I used a different ISP. They on the told me that the DSP from their router into the patch would be the only way their internet would work. It works now in my office through ethernet but now I cannot get my nighthawk to work.

Comment: Thank you John.

Comment: When you say a plain router, so you mean for my office and get rid of nighthawk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a working Ethernet connection in your own office with working internet.

Now look at the back of your own router or any plain router. The WAN connection is at the back.

Connect this WAN jack by an Ethernet cable to the working network connection above. Start up the router and you should have Internet from one of the Ethernet LAN outlets.

To administer the router, log in to the admin interface (nominally 192.168.1.1) and make a user name and password. This need not be (and should not be) the same as the comm room unless they so mandate.

Comment: Thank you. Hopefully I will get this working in the morning. Appreciate you helping me.